# javascript problem with multiple button clicks

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am new to javascript and just want to make a simple webpage where the user enters a number (id="number") and then clicks one of several buttons (btn6 or btn7 ect) which then multiplies the inputted number by the number on the button.  The below code works, but not if the button is clicked more than once. Why is this and how can I change it?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>L100 variables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please enter a number </p>
  <input type="text" id="number">

  <button id="btn2"> x2</button>
  <button id="btn6"> x6</button>
  <button id="btn7"> x7</button>
  <button id="btn78"> x78</button>
  <button id="btn90"> x90</button>


  <p id="output"> </p>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {

      var input = document.getElementById("number").value;
      var output = input * 2;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what happens when the button is clicked a second time? does the output html remain the same as after the first click? have you tried putting a console.log or debugger statement inside the click handler to get a better idea for the current behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of the *output* to `input * 2`. Clicking the button again works just fine: it multiplies the value of the input by two, and sends that to the output. If the input value has not changed in the interim, the output value will be the same, and it will *look* like clicking the button again did nothing.

How to fix this depends on what exact behavior you want. If you want to multiply the input several times in a row, and have it go up each time, all you need to do is set the input element's value instead of the output element's value, like so:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>L100 variables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please enter a number </p>
  <input type="text" id="number">

  <button id="btn2"> x2</button>
  <button id="btn6"> x6</button>
  <button id="btn7"> x7</button>
  <button id="btn78"> x78</button>
  <button id="btn90"> x90</button>

  <p id="output"> </p>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {

      var inputElement = document.getElementById("number");
      var input = inputElement.value;
      var output = input * 2;
      inputElement.value = output;

      // optional:
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working, just not how you're imagining it. Currently you're multiplying the input by 2 and the output will be the input * 2. If you keep pressing your multiply by 2 button the input remains the same so your output remains the same. If you want your behavior to multiply by 2 over and over then you need to adjust the input to also be multiplied by 2.

Something like:

```
    document.getElementById("number").value = output;
```

Comment: You can't set the `.innerHTML` of an `<input>`, you need to set `.value` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the catch